# Thomae's function, doubt in continuous proof in the irrationals.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was studying about this proof and i almost understand all of it, i just have one doubt there, the proof i found is the following;

Let f be defined by;

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}\\
\frac{1}{q} & \text{if $x = \frac{p}{q}$ where $(p,q) = 1$ and q > 0}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Let r be irrational. Then f(r)=0. Let m be a positive integer. Then r is in a unique interval of the form ( k/m,(k+1)/m). Let dm = min{|r −k/m|, |r −(k+1)/m|} and let δm = min{d1, d2, . . . , dm}. Notice δm < 1/m.
Let ε > 0 be given. Choose m so that 1/m < ε. Let δ=δm. If x is a rational number with |x − r| < δ then x =p/q with gcd(p,q)=1 and q > m. Hence $0<f(x)=1/q < 1/m < ε$ . If x is irrational, f(x) = 0. So for any x, with |x − r| < δ, |f(x) − f(r)| < ε . This proves that f is continuous at any irrational number.

i think i understand the most part of it, but i just have a big question quen it says that q < m, i don't know how he can ensure that, because we are taking m large enough to be 1/m < ε, so, how you ensure that m > q is not going to happen?

Comment: What is $f$? Seems like you are assuming context.

Comment: f is the thomae's function, i will add it right now, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we had $q\le m$, then $\delta_m \le d_q \le |r-x|$ (since $x=\frac pq$); but $|r-x| < \delta = \delta_m$, a contradiction.

Comment: Oh now i see it, actually i was a little confused of not using that part, thanks for your answer!