# Thomae function is continuous at $x\notin\mathbb Q$, discontinuous at $x\in\mathbb Q$

Tags: calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let f be the [Thomae function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) aka the popcorn function. Use the epsilon-delta to prove that f is continuous for all irrational numbers and discontinuous for all rational numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please expand your post to add your thoughts or progress on the problem so we can help you where you are stuck.

Comment: I think it will be in sequential approach..

Comment: BTW exactly the same question was posted on the same day by another user. Now the question is deleted, here is link for 10k+ users: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114732/help-with-proof-using-epsilon-delta-please

Comment: @jess_001 If both accounts belong to you, you can merge them following the instruction given [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8403/announcement-new-user-merge-policy-tool).

Comment: I will also point out that you can easily find many posts about this problem, simple using Google for [some reasonable search phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=Thomae+continuous+site:math.stackexchange.com). For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207118/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036269/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530097/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860082/, ...